# DB2 Multiple Table Joins Yields Duplicate Rows

Tags: sql, join, db2, distinct

I'm having difficulties joining multiple tables together; when doing so, I'm getting duplicate data which I do not expect.

[image]

Essentially, every Application can have one or more forms. Each applicant can have one or more forms. And one applicant can have one or more addresses; however, for sake of simplicity, I only want to return one address.

```
SELECT
    APPLICANT.FIRST_NAME,
    APPLICANT.LAST_NAME,
    ADDRESS.STREET,
    ADDRESS.CITY,
    ADDRESS.STATE,
    ADDRESS.POSTAL_CODE,
    FORM.SERIAL
FROM
    APPLICATION JOIN
    FORM ON
        FORM.APPLICATION_SERIAL = APPLICATION.SERIAL JOIN
    APPLICANT ON
        FORM.APPLICATION_SERIAL = APPLICANT.APPLICATION_SERIAL JOIN
    APPLICANT_ADDRESS ON
        APPLICANT.SERIAL = APPLICANT_ADDRESS.APPLICANT_SERIAL
```

When running this query, if an application has two applicants, each with their own address, and each with a form, the results is duplicated twice for each applicant. I have tried selecting `DISTINCT` columns as well as grouping by serial, last name, first name, etc, but to no avail.

```
+------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| First_Name | Last_Name |     Street      |     City     | State | Postal_code | Form_Serial |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| John       | Doe       | 123 Main Street | Magical City | ZZ    |       00000 |         001 |
| John       | Doe       | 123 Main Street | Magical City | ZZ    |       00000 |         001 |
| Jane       | Doe       | 456 Y Street    | Another City | ZZ    |       00000 |         002 |
| Jane       | Doe       | 456 Y Street    | Another City | ZZ    |       00000 |         002 |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

What is the best way to prevent duplicate rows when joining these tables together?

Comment: You are missing a join condition between `FORM` and `APPLICANT`.

Comment: So if I apply for something twice, does that mean I have two `Applicant` records?  If the address would be on a `Form`, shouldn't that mean the address belongs to the form?  (Even if I, as an applicant, also have an address)

Answer (score 1):

The statement "Each applicant can have one or more forms" doesn't follow from your schema - the `Form` entity is related to the `Application` entity, but not to the `Applicant` one.
It would be good to have sample data you get duplicates on.

```
WITH 
  APPLICATION (Serial) as (values
  (1)
) 
, FORM (Serial, Application_serial) as (values
  ('001', 1)
--, ('002', 1)
) 
, APPLICANT (Serial, Application_Serial, First_Name, Last_Name) as (values
  (1, 1, 'John', 'Doe')
, (2, 1, 'Jane', 'Doe')
)
, ADDRESS (Serial, Applicant_Serial, Street, City, State, Postal_code) as (values
  (1, 1, '123 Main Street', 'Magical City', 'ZZ', '00000')
, (2, 2, '456 Y Street', 'Another City', 'ZZ', '00000')
)
SELECT 
  APPLICANT.FIRST_NAME, APPLICANT.LAST_NAME
, ADDRESS.STREET, ADDRESS.CITY, ADDRESS.STATE, ADDRESS.POSTAL_CODE
, FORM.SERIAL AS FORM_SERIAL
FROM APPLICATION 
JOIN FORM ON FORM.APPLICATION_SERIAL = APPLICATION.SERIAL 
JOIN APPLICANT ON FORM.APPLICATION_SERIAL = APPLICANT.APPLICATION_SERIAL 
JOIN ADDRESS ON APPLICANT.SERIAL = ADDRESS.APPLICANT_SERIAL;

FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME STREET          CITY         STATE POSTAL_CODE FORM_SERIAL
---------- --------- --------------- ------------ ----- ----------- -----------
John       Doe       123 Main Street Magical City ZZ    00000       001
Jane       Doe       456 Y Street    Another City ZZ    00000       001

  2 record(s) selected.
```

My example doesn't return duplicates. 
But you get your results if you uncomment the 2-nd `Form` of this `Application` (not `Applicant`). Namely this 2-nd `Form` record is the reason you get duplicates in your output. 
You should decide what to return in the `FORM_SERIAL` column in case of multiple `Forms` for given `Application`.